# Can I restore only changed files from Crash Plan cloud backup?

Tags: restore, crashplan

I have two hard drives:

- C drive has the windows install
- D drive holds the user profiles (desktops, documents etc)

D drive was being backed up to Crash Plan, and this morning D drive failed.

As well as the Crash Plan backup, I also have a backup of D: drive on an external USB hard drive, but it's a couple of months old. To save time, I was wondering if it's possible to copy the contents of this external drive onto a replacement D: drive, and then only restore from Crash Plan the files that have since changed (plus new files)? We have a very slow connection, so this could potentially save quite a lot of time.

Does that sound feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the steps you list will not have the desired effect. CrashPlan will need to restore the entire online backup if it is selected for Restore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was the conclusion I came to in the end. It can only overwrite or rename, which is a shame - there is no option for skipping existing files, or for only overwriting older files. Would be really nice to have these features.